# How to configure Google Cloud Pub/Sub for test, staging, and production?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-pubsub

I saw this document.
(https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#environments)

> The first part of maintaining a system like Cloud Pub/Sub is to have the ability to test the software before it is used by customers. In order to make that possible, there are three Cloud Pub/Sub environments: test, staging, and production.

But I can't find where to configure it.

My purpose is that developers can't pub/sub from production topics.

I tried to create two service account, one for the developer, one for production. But if I give the developer roles/pubsub.editor, a developer can also pub/sub at production.

Or is there a way to just let the person who published it can subscribe.

Note: I am using Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 from nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section of the documentation refers to the process by which the Cloud Pub/Sub service itself is tested and rolled out; these are not separate environments designed for use by customers to test out their own software.

If you want to set up your own test, staging, and production environments, you will at the very least need separate topics and subscriptions. You could consider having separate projects entirely for your different environments if you want to achieve complete isolation. This is a pretty typical way to separate testing and development from production.